# Enable checkboxes when a <select> option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, checkbox

I'm creating a "Request a quote" page. I'm quite new to this, and I want to create a condition, when selecting options from a **select** area:

When you select a service, a `div` removes class ".disabled" and the checkboxes remove attribute "disabled" (unclickable)

What I want to do is the following, after selecting the option "Mobile Application", this will happen:

1. Class `disabled` is removed from

   ```
   <div id="appoptions" class="disabled"></div>
   ```
2. Attribute `disabled` is also removed, from checkboxes:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox "class="servico" disabled>
   ```
3. In the end, both must be like:

   ```
   <div id="appoptions"></div>
   <input type="checkbox "class="servico">
   ```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/ujgx4st3/3/

Any help appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" id="service">Choose one of the options</option>
    <optgroup label=""></optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Full webpage">
        <option value="webpage">Create a new, custom website</option>
        <option value="reweb">Modernize our current website</option>
        <option value="trasnf">I don't know what I'm looking for</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label=""></optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Design Services">
        <option value="logo">Logo Design</option>
        <option value="branding">Branding</option>
        <option value="webdesign">Webpages design</option>
        <option value="mobile">Social Design <label class="hidden-xs">(Youtube, Facebook, Twitter, etc)</label></option>
        <option value="uxui">Mobile UX/UI</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label=""></optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Web Development">
        <option value="manage">Website Management</option>
        <option value="manage">Update to Responsive</option>
        <option value="coding">Page Coding</option>
        <option value="software">Software Programming</option>
        <option value="mobile">Mobile Application</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label=""></optgroup>

    <optgroup label="SEO & Social Media">
        <option value="smarket">Social Marketing <label class="hidden-xs">(Facebook, Twitter, Youtube, etc)</label></option>
        <option value="seo">Search Engine Optimization</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label=""></optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Website with CMS">
        <option value="wordpress">Wordpress</option>
        <option value="joomla">Joomla</option>
        <option value="drupal">Drupal</option>
        <option value="magento">Magento</option>
    </optgroup>

</select>


<div id="appoptions1" class="col-md-3 disabled">

    <div style="margin: 25px 0;">
        <label><b>Application options</b> <small>(mobile)</small></label></br></br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="android" disabled class="servico">Android</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="apple" disabled class="servico">Apple</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="windows" disabled class="servico">Windows Phone</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="webapp" disabled class="servico">Web application</br>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function enable_cb() {
  var state = $('.check').attr('disabled');

    if ( $('select option:selected').attr() == 'mobile' ) {
        $('#addoptions').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the requirement?  Is there any difference between your later requirements and your first requirement?  Or is it just a specific example?

Comment: What I want to do, is select the option "mobile application" on my html select, after doing so, my div id "appoptions", removes the class="disabled", also my checkbox class="servico", looses the attribute "disabled"

Comment: @uniqezor please edit your question and add the clarification. This makes it easier for other users to understand your problem.

Comment: Agreed.  It is difficult to tell where you are currently stuck, @uniqezor.

Comment: Ive changed the topic description. Sorry for the mess

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting an error on your Javascript console, try the following:

```
function enable_cb(element) {
  var state = $(element).attr('disabled');
  $(element).prop('disabled', !state);
}
```

If you're using jQuery 1.6+, avoid using prop( ) since it has been deprecated in favor of attr( );

Comment: What I've done is this:

function enable_cb() {
  var state = $('select option:selected').attr('disabled');
  $(state).prop('disabled', !state);

    if (state == 'mobile' ) {
        $('#addoptions').removeClass('disabled');
    } else{
        return false;
    };